# FileNotFoundError when using Pandas to_parquet but path works writing a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, pyspark, azure-storage, azure-synapse

Why am I getting a `FileNotFoundError` using Pandas but not `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`?

All the code is in a Azure Synapse Notebook using PySpark. This first section works:

```
SourceFileName = "2023-05-26-14-17-11-821-object.parquet"
TestFileName = "Test"
AzureBlobStorageAccountName = "redacted"

SourceFilePath = f'abfss://datalake@' + AzureBlobStorageAccountName + '.dfs.core.windows.net/Bronze/ServiceBus/Object/' + SourceFileName

dfBronze = spark.read.load(SourceFilePath, format='parquet').cache()

dfBronze.createOrReplaceTempView("Bronze")

dfSilver = spark.read.load('abfss://datalake@' + AzureBlobStorageAccountName + '.dfs.core.windows.net/Silver/ServiceBus/Object/*.parquet', format='parquet').cache()

dfSilver.createOrReplaceTempView("Silver") #<-- Successfully writes DataFrame to Azure Storage Account
```

This portion using Pandas does not work

```
import pandas as pd

dict = pd.DataFrame({
    "ObjectId": 45
    "AdditionalSpecialties": [
        { "SpecialtyId": "38",
          "Specialty": "Family" }
    ]
},{
    "ObjectId": 185,
    "AdditionalSpecialties": [
        { "SpecialtyId": "498",
          "Specialty": "Pandas" },
        { "SpecialtyId": "502",
          "Specialty": "Are Cute" }
    ]
})

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

TestFilePath = f'abfss://datalake@' + AzureBlobStorageAccountName + '.dfs.core.windows.net/Bronze/ServiceBus/Object/' + TestFileName

print(df)

df.to_parquet(TestFilePath) #<-- Error happens here writing Pandas DataFrame to Azure Storage Account
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use the path as below.

```
abfs://<container_name>/<path_to_file>
```

OR

```
abfs://container_name@Storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/path_to_file
```

Code:

```
df.to_parquet('abfs://dats@jgsadls.dfs.core.windows.net/output/pd_df2.parquet', storage_options = {'linked_service' : '<linked_service_name>'})

# OR

df.to_parquet('abfs://dats/output/pd_df2.parquet', storage_options = {'linked_service' : 'AzureDataLakeStorage1'})
```

Here, I used storage options and given linked service. I believe, in your synapse there will be linked service. If not create linked service for your storage account.

Go To Manage > Linked services > New > Select Adls2.

Give name and required details.

Output:
[image]

Files are written in **dats** container.

[image]

For more information, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool) documentation.